# Disable or hide inactive buttons (fab and toolbar) - guidelines?

Tags: android, android-layout

Could someone please let me know what a recommended practice is on android?  For example, I currently set background tint color of fab to grey when it is disabled.  I do the same to buttons in the app bar.  I'm not quite sure if this is a correct approach.
Any pointers as well as any examples of apps for reference would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can also set the Alpha to .5f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Material Design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-raised-buttons), a disable button (tinted or not) should be;

- Light Background/Theme: Disabled text: 26% #000000, Disabled button: 12% #000000
- Dark Background/Theme: Disabled text: 30% #FFFFFF, Disabled button: 12% #FFFFFF

Though, I would hide both types of buttons if they are to be "disabled", to free up space on the user's screen of buttons they cannot use.